# Why must SUSY be broken in SUGRA inflation?

Tags: supersymmetry, cosmological-inflation, supergravity

Why must supersymmetry be broken during the inflation in supergravity models? How does adding supersymmetry to power-law or Starobinsky models spoil inflation?

And is breaking of SUSY needed for both F-term and D-term inflations?

Comment: Do you have a reference? I'm not sure exactly what scenario you're describing

Comment: You can see here for example - "http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.2488v2.pdf", for general cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inflation we need to have a positive energy density $V>0$, which drives inflation. If [the VEV of] the F-term potential $V_F>0$, then we necessarily have F-term SUSY breaking. (Text in [] should be removed, see discussion below.)

psm

Comment: But isn't it sufficient that the inflaton has positive values during the inflation, without having a VEV?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Let $\phi$ be the inflaton. Then, during inflation we necessarily have $V(\phi)>0$ and SUSY is (spontaneously) broken.

Comment: But what does it have to do with VEV? VEV is the value of \phi when potential is at minimum. But during the inflation the potential is not at minimum, it is located at the plateau.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should edit that. During inflation we have $V>0$, that's it.

Comment: So, did I understand correctly that the form of the scalar potential  itself is not SUSY invariant? And only when V=0, SUSY is restored (?)

Comment: For global SUSY to be restored we must have $V=0$. For local SUSY (i.e. SUGRA) even $V=0$ violates SUSY (b/c $V \sim e^K(|DW|^2-3|W|^2)$). Being not a real expert on this I'd like to refer to Allanach's/Quevedo's lecture notes on SUSY (where I originally learned about the topics).